# How to get count based on buckets the values in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have below mentioned dataframe in R.

```
ID       Date         Type         Value
K-1      2018-01-01   A            4
K-2      2018-01-01   B            7
K-3      2018-01-01   C            12
K-4      2018-01-02   A            6
K-5      2018-01-02   A            4
K-6      2018-01-02   B            15
K-7      2018-01-02   B            10
```

I want to learn how to convert the dataframe in below given required dataframe, Where `A`, `B` and `C` should be static for every date, irrespective of if that particular type is available or not on that date.

In addition, I want to count the `ID` group by date and `Type`, in the bucket of `<5` ( If Value is between 1-4), `5-10` (if value is between 5 to 10) and `>10` (if value is higher than 10).

`sum` column should consist of the total of value for that particular date and Type as well.

`Count` column should consist of the count of `ID` group by particular date and `Type`.

Required DF

```
Date           Count      <5      5-10       >10      sum
2018-01-01      3         1        1          1        23
A               1         1        0          0        4
B               1         0        1          0        7
C               1         0        0          1        12
2018-01-02      4         1        2          1        35
A               2         1        1          0        10
B               2         0        1          1        25
C               0         0        0          0        0
```

My code:

```
Required_Output <- df1 %>%
  group_by(Date, Type) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(Count=n(),
                   A=sum(Type=='A'),
                   B=sum(Type=='B'),
                   C=sum(Type=='C')) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  complete(Date, Type, fill=list(`Count`=0,A=0, B=0, C=0))
```

The above code didn't give me the desired output :(

Comment: Mixing dates and factor levels is probably not the cleanest solution. Would I be correct in guessing that you need this just for presentation purposes? If not, you'll probably have to think of having another variable called Type.

Comment: There was a [nearly identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55528913/how-to-group-by-variables-in-bucket-r) by user @VectorJX that since got removed. Coincidence? Same course? Same user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some steps could be further simplified, but the following works.

```
library(tidyverse)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  mutate(Result = case_when(
    Value < 5                        ~"<5",
    Value >= 5 & Value <= 10         ~"5-10",
    Value > 10                       ~">10"
  )) %>%
  group_by(Date, Type, Result) %>%
  summarize(sum = sum(Value)) %>%
  mutate(Flag = 1L) %>%
  spread(Result, Flag, fill = 0L) %>%
  group_by(Date, Type) %>%
  summarize_all(list(~sum(.))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  complete(Date, Type)

dat2[is.na(dat2)] <- 0

dat3 <- dat2 %>% mutate(Count = rowSums(select(., -Date, -Type, -sum)))

dat4 <- dat3 %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  summarize_at(vars(-Type), list(~sum(.))) 

dat_final <- map2_dfr(split(dat4, f = dat4$Date),
                      split(dat3, f = dat3$Date),
                      ~bind_rows(.x %>% rename(Type = Date), 
                                 .y %>% select(-Date)))

dat_final2 <- dat_final %>%
  select(Date = Type, Count, `<5`, `5-10`, `>10`, sum)
dat_final2
# # A tibble: 8 x 6
#   Date       Count  `<5` `5-10` `>10`   sum
#   <chr>      <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 2018-01-01     3     1      1     1    23
# 2 A              1     1      0     0     4
# 3 B              1     0      1     0     7
# 4 C              1     0      0     1    12
# 5 2018-01-02     4     1      2     1    35
# 6 A              2     1      1     0    10
# 7 B              2     0      1     1    25
# 8 C              0     0      0     0     0
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "ID       Date         Type         Value
'K-1'      '2018-01-01'   A            4
'K-2'      '2018-01-01'   B            7
'K-3'      '2018-01-01'   C            12
'K-4'      '2018-01-02'   A            6
'K-5'     '2018-01-02'   A            4
'K-6'      '2018-01-02'   B            15
'K-7'      '2018-01-02'   B            10",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Count is not coming correct with my dataframe, also I need to make the buckets (i.e `<5`, `5-10`, `>10`) static, irrespective of if the value fall under that bucket for that particular day or not.

Comment: I thought my output is the same as your desired output?

Comment: Yes for the sample data its working fine, but when using large data its giving wrong count, I have also tried using `count = n(ID)` in `summarize`.

Comment: Since my solution works on your example dataset, it means there are some key differences between your example dataset and your real-world dataset. It would be your responsibility to figure out what are the key differences.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to figure it out.